# How to find nodes of an undamped free-vibrating 2 DOF pitch and bounce system

Tags: mechanical-engineering, vibration

I am working on a 2DOF non-forced pitch and bounce model for an engineering project.

I've found the values for my natural frequencies, and the initial conditions which make the system resonate in a certain mode.

I now want to find the system's nodes. Can nodes only exist if the system is resonating in a mode?

Or can I get nodes when the system's motion is composed of contributions from both modes?

Comment: Did you work out this question, let's just say I have the exact same issue and probably for the exact same reason (r are 1.69 and -1.01?)

Comment: Hahaha too late